# Combining environment with if - statement leads to errors

Tags: environments, counters

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{gtrcrd}
\newcounter{Cnt}
\setcounter{Cnt}{1}
\input EileenBl.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{EileenBl}{xl}{n}}
\newenvironment{Testenvironment}[2][]{%
    \lettrine[lhang=1, nindent=0pt, lines=1]{\initfamily #2}{}%
}{}
\newenvironment{BigEnv}
{
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%       \centering
%       \ifnum\theCnt=1%
            \begin{Testenvironment}%
%       \fi         
}
{
%   \ifnum\theCnt=1%
        \end{Testenvironment}%  
%   \fi
    \end{minipage}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{BigEnv}
    A \blindtext
\end{BigEnv}
\end{document}
```

I want to have the `lettrine` custom environment only if the counter `Cnt` is set to 1, else not. When compiling it as shown above, I get no errors, but the environment for lettrine is always applied. If I uncomment the commented lines, then I get a lot of errors such as `! Extra \endcsname.`. Why? And how can I still get my intention in LaTeX?

Comment: Well, `\TestEnvironment` tries to read the `\fi` then

Comment: I'm not sure why using an environment for typesetting a lettrine.

Comment: Is there an alternative for that? The text is already in an environment (per design), and I do not want to add the lettrine environment to every text...

Comment: @arc_lupus: I hate this approach but you can use a command like an environment, i.e. `\newcommand{\foo}` and say `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` anyway. Putting it in other words: the command `\foo` environment name. (With some cautions, of course)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: How would that solve my problem? Anyway, good information, thanks!

Comment: @arc_lupus: Well, at the moment there's a solution, I think ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you desire? I would apply the `\if....` test inside of the `TestEnvironment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{gtrcrd}
\newcounter{Cnt}
\setcounter{Cnt}{1}
\input EileenBl.fd

\newif\ifuselettrine
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{EileenBl}{xl}{n}}
\newenvironment{Testenvironment}[2][]{%
  \ifuselettrine%
  \lettrine[lhang=1, nindent=0pt, lines=1]{\initfamily #2}{}%
  \fi
}{}
\newenvironment{BigEnv}
{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{Testenvironment}%
  }{%
  \end{Testenvironment}%  
\end{minipage}
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{BigEnv}
    A \blindtext
\end{BigEnv}
\uselettrinetrue
\begin{BigEnv}
    A \blindtext
\end{BigEnv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach, with a `fakeenvironment` and using `\LetLtxMacro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{gtrcrd}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\newcounter{Cnt}
\setcounter{Cnt}{1}
\input EileenBl.fd

\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{EileenBl}{xl}{n}}
\newenvironment{Testenvironment}[2][]{%
  \lettrine[lhang=1, nindent=0pt, lines=1]{\initfamily #2}{}%
}{}

%Now let's define a dummy environment that does absolutely nothing
\newenvironment{fakeenvironment}{}{}
\newenvironment{BigEnv}
{%
  \ifnum\value{Cnt}=1\relax
  %Ah, the 'real' environment is requested, so make `\fakeenvironment` behave like `Testenvironment`, by copying its code!
  \LetLtxMacro\fakeenvironment\Testenvironment%
  \LetLtxMacro\endfakeenvironment\endTestenvironment
  \fi
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{fakeenvironment}
    }{%
    \end{fakeenvironment}%  
  \end{minipage}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{BigEnv}
    A \blindtext
\end{BigEnv}
\setcounter{Cnt}{0}
\begin{BigEnv}
    A \blindtext
\end{BigEnv}
\setcounter{Cnt}{1}
\begin{BigEnv}
    A \blindtext
\end{BigEnv}



\end{document}
```

Comment: My problem with the current approach is: How is the status of `Cnt` taken into account? It should be checked inside of the environment `BigEnv`. Is that possible?

Comment: @arc_lupus: I will check later on, ok?

Comment: No problem for me, I have time for that project.

Comment: @arc_lupus: See the update, please

Comment: Yes, that did it, thanks! But how does it work exactly? What is the purpose of `\fakeenvironment`?

Comment: @arc_lupus: Basically it's the trick I mentioned in the comments below your post. `fakeenvironment` is changed into usage of `Testenvironment` if the counter has the value of 1, otherwise it does **nothing** ;-) The usage `\if....` over the grouping feature of an environment is difficult (or even impossible)